# How to Export Records in batches in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssis

As already said in the title, how do i export a table into Excel file but into batches? I have total 300 thousands records in one table. I exported it into Excel but when it hit the 65536 records in Excel, operation failed. (may be coz of limit of rows in excel).  So how to get around with this situation?

All i need is a table exported from one server and imported it into another server. I can't use Linked Server coz of limitation of VPNs (both servers are on different VPN network).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Export to a CSV file instead of an XLS - there's no size limit in CSVs.  I get 10 GB+ CSV files from my clients on a regular basis.

Comment: When I export it to txt file, it complains about this:- Error 0xc020802e: Data Flow Task 1: The data type for "input column "Comment" (166)" is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: @Novice, you are hitting the max capacity for XLS.  A XLSX can go further, but you are better off using a CSV file for this as @JNK noted.

Comment: @Novice - that's an indication that you have unicode text in your tables.  check the box for "unicode" on the export wizard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is a limitation of Excel in any version eralier than 2007.

If you are going from one server to another server, it is silly to use Excel anyway as it has all kinds of bad issues with data conversion. Use a pipe delimted text file and life will be much better. Frankly SSIS is so bad at handling Excel, we try very hard to get clients to accept a text file even if the file is going to a person who wants to play with it in Excel (Excel can easily open a text file.)

Comment: Earlier I tried to export in text file, but one of my field is nvarchar, and it gives an error (mentioned about).